# which ubuntu version is suitable for my laptop?

Tags: system-installation

I'm using an older laptop. My laptop Configuration is as follows,

- Intel Celeron processor 2.00 GHz
- 2 GB of RAM
- 80 GB of Hard Disk

Comment: please take care of posting properly with format.

Answer (score 1):

Xubuntu 12.04 LTS. Its fast and low on resource and is supported till April,2015.

Download from [HERE](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/)

Comment: Xubuntu 13.10 support ends in July,2014.

Comment: Also, 80GB are more than enough.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you  Lubuntu , Xubuntu & Ubuntu Minimal install.

[To know more about installation requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements#Lightweight%20GUI%20alternative%20%28Xubuntu%20and%20Lubuntu%29)

[To know more about low memory systems](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/LowMemorySystems)

Answer (score 0):

Any environment of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32 bit. That should work smoothly.